# How to sort a custom column in ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm trying to sort a custom column on the index page in ActiveAdmin that shows data provided by a helper method.

I have tried multiple sort solutions and none of them worked. I was thinking about trying to sort with custom scopes but I am looking for a solution in the Active Admin.

```
 index do
    selectable_column
    id_column
    column ("Driver") { |cd| link_to("#{cd.campaign_driver.full_name}", admin_driver_path(cd.campaign_driver.driver_id)) }
    column :started_at
    column :ended_at
    column ("Distance(km)") { |route| route_distance(route) }
    column ("Clean distance(km)") { |route| route_clean_distance(route) }
    column ("Distance diff(km)") { |route| route_distance_diff(route) }
    column ("Duration") { |route| route_duration(route) }
    column ("Average speed") { |route| route_avg_speed(route) }
    actions
  end
```

The 'Distance Diff' column should be sortable.

Comment: Welcome Srdjan :) What is the name of the resource that is being registered? Am guesssing ```Route```, but unsure as you also use ```|cd|``` for the ```driver``` column?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to refactor your method first, make it to scoped_collection.

```
controller do
  def scoped_collection
    Route.select("routes.*, (routes.ended_at-routes.ended_at) AS distance_diff_route")
  end
end
```

Then rewrite your index column to

```
column :distance_diff_route, sortable: :distance_diff_route
```

Answer (score 0):

In short, sorting by virtual attribute is not possible by the ways you tried to use.

Here is why. When you request the index page to be sorted by an attribute, database query is created, asking DB to sort records by that column. In that query, filters (if provided) are applied and resulting records in your `drivers` table are sorted by the selected real attribute and only a subset (depending on your paging setup in `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` `config.default_per_page = 30`) is returned. Your helper methods are applied to this subset (and therefore if it worked, it would only sort there 30 or so records). The database is not aware of your virtual attribute and cannot sort all records accordingly.

There are at least two solutions to this:

#### 1) Default scope

Easy solution is using Rails' own `default_scope`. It modifies the base query that is used as a base for model's query builder. You can offload the construction of the virtual fields there and then use it in Rails, see example below.
There are downsides: 1) it's going to get difficult if your virtual fields depend on other tables, 2) usage of default scope is often advised against - google "rails default scope bad" to catch up.

```
class Route < ApplicationRecord
  default_scope { select(Arel.star, 'md5(name) hashed_name') }
  ...
end

ActiveAdmin.register Route do
  index do
    column :hashed_name, sortable: true
  end
end
```

#### 2) View based model

Proper, but also more complicated solution is to create a database view that will compute all the virtual fields you need and then build a Rails model based on that view. Here is a resource that can help you achieve that - https://danchak99.wordpress.com/enterprise-rails/chapter-11-view-backed-models/